# How can I improve code that finds the n-samples vector subset meeting certain criteria?

Tags: matlab, syntax, vectorization, reshape

In Matlab, given a vector A (please, find it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/otropedwxj0lki7/A.mat?dl=0 ), how could I find the n-samples vector subset with the smallest range (or standard deviation)?

I am trying a potential solution: reshaping the vector in columns, performing range of each column and selecting the smallest. However, reshape does not always works well when applied to other examples with different lengths. How could this be worked around in an easier and more efficient way?

```
Fs = 1000; % sampling frequency
time = round(length(A)/Fs)-1; % calculate approximated rounded total length in time
A_reshaped = reshape(A(1:time*Fs), [], time/2); % reshape A (deleting some samples at the end) in time/2 columns
D(1,:) = mean(A_reshaped);
D(2,:) = range(A_reshaped);
[~,idx] = min(D(2,:));
Value = D(1,idx);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To find the n-sample with minimum range you can sort the vector and subtract the first section of the sorted vector from the last section. Then use index of the minimum to find the n-sample:

```
n=4
a= rand(1,10);
s= sort(a);
[~,I]=min(s(n:end)-s(1:end-n+1))
result = s(I:I+n-1)
```